# Elasticsearch Query: Exact match should show with the following priority

Tags: elasticsearch

When I am trying to search for **marble flooring** the following matches should be fetched

1. marble flooring
2. marbles flooring
3. flooring marble
4. flooring marbles
5. marble floor
6. marbles floor
7. marble
8. marbles
9. flooring
10. floor

```
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": [
              {
                  "multi_match": {
                      "query": "marble flooring",
                      "fields": [
                          "title^3",
                          "keywords.key_value^2",
                          "services.name^1"
                      ],
                      "type": "best_fields",
                      "operator": "and"
                  }
              }
          ]
      }
  }
}
```

as I dont want to use fuzziness, due to fuzziness. when am searching for **table**, in the results i am getting the results for **cable** as well

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

As it seems, you need to check for the base form of the words. meaning that searching for a word "jump" would also match for the words [jumping, jumped, jumps, etc.].

So as you said, definitely fuzziness could not be a good choice.

#### Recommended Solution

To do so you can use the [stemming feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/stemming.html). which convert words to their base form while indexing and searching for documents.

in the provided link you can read more on how to use such a feature in elasticsearch.

Comment: while indexing the document I have already used **stemmer**
`
"stemmer_filter": {
                    "type": "stemmer",
                    "name": "english"
                }`

Comment: So, could you please provide the output result for the query you run? (the query in the question). there might be the problem.
Also It would be helpful if you could provide the setting/mapping so that I can simulate the problem on my own.

Comment: **mappings**
`
{
  "indexname": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "keywords": {
          "properties": {
            "keyword_values": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "name": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "stemmer_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: **settings**
`
{
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "stemmer_analyzer": {
        "tokenizer": "standard",
        "filter": [
          stemmer_filter
        ]
      }
    },
    "filter": {
      "stemmer_filter": {
        "type": "stemmer",
        "name": "english"
      }
    }
  }
}
`